# scrollview on top of navigation bar and toolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I want to know how, if possible, one can keep the scrollview on top of the navigation bar. When I put the scrollview on my view controller it covers the whole screen except for the navigation bar and toolbar. I want to keep it on top of everything.

Comment: it would help if you share some of your code

Comment: I have a view controller which is embeded in a navigation controller. All i did was try to place a scrollview on that view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use containerView to achieve this because containerView can contain Navigation controller within it like other controller.

And Add scrollView within containerView like below shown -

[image]

Hope it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to put the scroll view "on top of" the navigation bar, and it is certainly something that Apple Devs never intended to be done. Generally (although certainly not always) that means that if you want your code to work consistently as new versions of Swift and iOS are released, you shouldn't do it. The other reason you shouldn't do it (probably) is that unless you setup some sort of fancy "touch through" system you would never be able to actually use the nav bar, at which point you might as well just save the trouble and not have a nav bar in the first place. You can, however, easily check a box in your storyboard to have the scrollview go *under* the nav bar, and have the nav bar be translucent so that you can see the scroll view content under it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think preset modal(`UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`) is what you're looking for.